# How to refactor similar methods?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I develop class that manages connections to external resources. Its responsibility is reading credentials from given source and returning authenticated connections, like:

```
def get_svn_connection(self):
    username, pwd=self.get_credentials("SVN")
    client=self.get_svn_client(username, pwd)
    return client

def get_db_connection(self):
    username, pwd, url, schema=self.get_credentials("DB")
    client=self.get_db_client(username, pwd, url, schema)
    return client
```

Today I met new use case: sometimes user needs to get only credentials without connection. So, following current solution, I have to create methods `get_svn_credentials`, `get_db_credentials` and so on. It looks very redundant so I want to refactor this structure.
My ideas are:

1. Create subclasses for every connection type and for each of them define methods `get_connection` and `get_credentials`. The problems are: 1) I want one class to rule all the connections; 2) I would have to use multi-inheritance (possible in Python, but would not work in, for example, Java - if I'll meet this problem in future)
2. Create methods `get_connection(type)` and `get_credentials(type)` and for every known connection type specified by string return corresponding instance. Problem is I have to create a switch which considered bad in OOP.
3. Use metaprogramming to generate methods for every connection types. Not obvious and Python-specific.

   How would you design this?

Comment: You already have `get_credentials(type)`, why do you think that having `get_connection(type)` would make things worse?

Comment: @Goyo, It's simplified code. In fact, it's `get_credentials(prefix, list_of_variables)` being called like `get_credentials("SVN", ["USERNAME", "PASSWORD"])` so it searches for  SVN_USER and SVN_PASSWORD. It's private function not planned for external use.

Comment: Then your question as it is written is misleading. Anyway I think you should just choose the API that best fits your users' needs and then implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Credentials class, which can be used to authenticate another function call:

```
class SvnCredentials:
    def __init__(username, password):
        self._username = username
        self._password = password

    def authenticate(function):
        return function(self._username, self._password)
```

Usage:

```
>>> credentials = SvnCredentials('AzureDiamond ', 'hunter2')
>>> client = credentials.authenticate(get_svn_client)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on Jean-Francois Fabre answer, you can do one function the following way

```
def get_svn_connection(self, decision_str):
  if decision_str = "DB":
    return self.get_connection("DB",self.get_db_client)
  if decision_str = "SVN":
    return self.get_connection(decision_str, self.get_svn_client)
```

I don't think you can do it any more concisely than that, and I am not convinced it is better than Jean's way...

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_svn_connection(self, credentials=False):
    username, pwd=self.get_credentials("SVN")
    if credentials:
        return (username, pwd)        
    client=self.get_svn_client(username, pwd)
    return client

def get_db_connection(self, credentials=False):
    username, pwd, url, schema=self.get_credentials("DB")
    if credentials:
        return (username, pwd, url, schema)
    client=self.get_db_client(username, pwd, url, schema)
    return client
```